# Thymeleaf fragment with parameters

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am quite new to Thymeleaf, I am trying to create a fragment and pass to it a variable in my Spring MVC application but I am stuck.

My code:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/utilities :: reviews(message=${reviews[0].review})"></div>
```

My fragments/utilities.html:

```
<div th:fragment="reviews(message)">
<div class="carousel-item">
    <div class="border border-light rounded p-4 mb-3">
        <div th:replace="utilities :: stars"></div>
        <p th:text="message" class="mt-2"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But it isn't working, I have also tried substituting th:replace with th:insert or th:include.

Note: I know for sure that reviews[0].review isn't empty

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the way you want to display `message`

Instead of

```
<p th:text="message" class="mt-2"></p>
```

Try to use

```
<p th:text="${message}" class="mt-2"></p>
```